# Error installing python-midi package on Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, installation, midi

I was trying to install some packages for python on Windows using pip and got the following error while trying to install python-midi:

```
(env) C:\Users\Asus\Documents\LEI\Algo-Rhythm>pip install python-midi
Collecting python-midi
  Using cached python-midi-v0.2.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-zqxbr1j2\python-midi\setup.py", line 42
        print "No sequencer available for '%s' platform." % platform
                                                    ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(print "No sequencer available for '%s' platform." % platform)?

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Asus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-zqxbr1j2\python-midi\
```

I looked for the file where the error occurs but I can't find it even while viewing hidden files. If anybody knows what might be causing this or has experienced this issue as well I would be glad to hear. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is ur python version?

Comment: python 3.6.4 64-bit

Comment: I guessed so, since in python 3.x, `print` needs to be called as a function with parentheses.
I would check if the package you are trying to install is still actively being supported or not.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about this difference between Python 2 and 3. I'll check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this error occurs is because this package is meant for Python 2. You can tell by the old style of print statement.

Python 2

```
print "hey"
```

Python 3

```
print("hey")
```

I'd recommend checking out [python3-midi](https://github.com/louisabraham/python3-midi) which has been forked out of the original `python-midi` package.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'm relatively recent to Python and didn't know about this difference, I'll check python3-midi to see if I can use it instead. If I want to use the original package, the only way to do so is by using Python 2, right?

Comment: That's correct. `python3-midi` was forked from the original `python-midi` package, so I don't see why the usage wouldn't be nearly identical.

Answer (score 0):

I have just updated the print statement in the setup.py file.

```
    def configure_platform():
        from sys import platform
        ns = __base__.copy()
        # currently, only the ALSA sequencer is supported
        if platform.startswith('linux'):
            setup_alsa(ns)
            pass
        else:
            print("No sequencer available for '%s' platform." % platform)
        return ns
```

I hope this might help you.